# Active session count for a given app pool?

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, iis-6, session

I'm running a .net 4.0 app in IIS6 in a separate app pool.

Is there a way to see a count of active sessions for that website?

I can see the active sessions in the performance counters, but only for all .net 4.0 apps, is there a way to break this down further? It's using in process session state.

Perhaps using powershell? Thanks for the help.